# Exception in thread "main" IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself

Tags: java, swing

I just started learning programming and am trying to create a program that calculates the income tax at 20%. the program compiles but keeps getting errors. The error states

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself

I don't understand what to change.

```
*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;

public class IncomeTax extends JFrame
{
// declarations
    Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);
    Color white = new Color(255, 255, 255);
    Color light_gray = new Color(192, 192, 192);

    DecimalFormat currency;

    JLabel grossIncomeJLabel;
    JTextField grossIncomeJTextField;

    JLabel amountTaxedJLabel;
    JTextField amountTaxedJTextField;
    JTextField currencyJTextField;

    JLabel amountDeductedJLabel;
    JTextField amountDeductedJTextField;


    JLabel netIncomeJLabel;
    JTextField netIncomeJTextField;


    JButton enterJButton;
    JButton clearJButton;

double grossIncome;
double amountTaxed;
double amountDeducted;
double netIncome;

public IncomeTax()
    {
            createUserInterface();
    }

    public void createUserInterface()
    {
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setBackground(white);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    // initialize components

    // input
    grossIncomeJLabel = new JLabel ();
    grossIncomeJLabel.setBounds (50, 20, 150, 20);
    grossIncomeJLabel.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    grossIncomeJLabel.setText ("Enter Gross Income:");
    grossIncomeJLabel.setForeground(black);
    grossIncomeJLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    contentPane.add(grossIncomeJLabel);

    grossIncomeJTextField = new JTextField();
    grossIncomeJTextField.setBounds(200, 20, 100, 20);
    grossIncomeJTextField.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    grossIncomeJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    grossIncomeJTextField.setForeground(black);
    grossIncomeJTextField.setBackground(white);
    grossIncomeJTextField.setEditable(true);
    contentPane.add(grossIncomeJTextField);


    //outputs
    amountTaxedJLabel = new JLabel();
    amountTaxedJLabel.setBounds(50, 50, 150, 20);
    amountTaxedJLabel.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    amountTaxedJLabel.setText("Amount Taxed");
    amountTaxedJLabel.setForeground(black);
    amountTaxedJLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    amountTaxedJLabel.add(amountTaxedJLabel);

    amountTaxedJTextField = new JTextField();
    amountTaxedJTextField.setBounds(200, 50, 100, 20);
    amountTaxedJTextField.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    amountTaxedJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    amountTaxedJTextField.setForeground(black);
    amountTaxedJTextField.setBackground(white);
    amountTaxedJTextField.setEditable(false);
    contentPane.add(amountTaxedJTextField);

    amountDeductedJLabel = new JLabel();
    amountDeductedJLabel.setBounds(50, 80, 150, 20);
    amountDeductedJLabel.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    amountDeductedJLabel.setText("Amount Deducted:");
    amountDeductedJLabel.setForeground(black);
    amountDeductedJLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    contentPane.add(amountDeductedJLabel);

    amountDeductedJTextField = new JTextField();
    amountDeductedJTextField.setBounds(200, 80, 100, 20);
    amountDeductedJTextField.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    amountDeductedJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    amountDeductedJTextField.setForeground(black);
    amountDeductedJTextField.setBackground(white);
    amountDeductedJTextField.setEditable(false);
    contentPane.add(amountDeductedJTextField);

    netIncomeJLabel = new JLabel();
    netIncomeJLabel.setBounds(50, 110, 150, 20);
    netIncomeJLabel.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    netIncomeJLabel.setText("Net Income:");
    netIncomeJLabel.setForeground(black);
    netIncomeJLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    contentPane.add(netIncomeJLabel);

    netIncomeJTextField = new JTextField();
    netIncomeJTextField.setBounds(200, 110, 100, 20);
    netIncomeJTextField.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    netIncomeJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    netIncomeJTextField.setForeground(black);
    netIncomeJTextField.setBackground(white);
    netIncomeJTextField.setEditable(false);
    contentPane.add(netIncomeJTextField);

    // control
    enterJButton = new JButton();
    enterJButton.setBounds(50, 210, 100, 20);
    enterJButton.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    enterJButton.setText("Enter");
    enterJButton.setForeground(black);
    enterJButton.setBackground(white);
    contentPane.add(enterJButton);
    enterJButton.addActionListener(

        new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    enterJButtonActionPerformed(event);
                }
            }
        );

        clearJButton = new JButton();
        clearJButton.setBounds(200, 210, 100, 20);
        clearJButton.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        clearJButton.setText("Clear");
        clearJButton.setForeground(black);
        clearJButton.setBackground(white);
        contentPane.add(clearJButton);
        clearJButton.addActionListener(

            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    clearJButtonActionPerformed(event);
                }
            }
        );

        // set properties of application’s window
        setTitle("Income Tax");         // set title
        setSize( 400, 400 );        // set window size
        setVisible(true);           // display window
        }

        // main method
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
              IncomeTax application = new IncomeTax();
              application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        public void enterJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

        // get input
        grossIncome = Double.parseDouble(grossIncomeJTextField.getText());

        // process data
        final double Tax_Rate = .20;
        amountTaxed = Tax_Rate;
        amountDeducted = grossIncome * Tax_Rate;
        netIncome = grossIncome - amountDeducted;

        //display results
        currency = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");

        amountTaxedJTextField.setText("" + currency.format(amountTaxed));
        amountDeductedJTextField.setText("" + currency.format(amountDeducted));
        netIncomeJTextField.setText("" + currency.format(netIncome));
}

    public void clearJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        grossIncomeJTextField.setText("");
        grossIncomeJTextField.requestFocusInWindow();
        amountTaxedJTextField.setText("");
        amountDeductedJTextField.setText("");
        netIncomeJTextField.setText("");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Horrible heading !!! Please fix it

Comment: I've fixed your questions heading. In the future, please take care to make your question headings as succinct but also as informative as possible. Note that the exception tells you exactly what line the problem is on, and exactly what you're doing wrong; it's not very cryptic at all. You're adding something to itself and shouldn't do that.

Comment: When you said "complies" do you mean "compiles". Also in the error log it tells you the line where the error occurs. Can you post that line number?

Comment: It is also a big help if you can point out which line is causing the exception. Stacktraces usually include them, and it's often very hard to tell where the problem is without this information.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to use a floating point type like `double` to represent monetary values. You should either store them as a whole number of cents or use Java's `BigDecimal` class.

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
amountTaxedJLabel.add(amountTaxedJLabel);
```

I think you meant

```
contentPane.add(amountTaxedJLabel);
```

In the prior, you are adding a view to itself.
In the later, you are adding it to your contentPane.

Comment: @user4059399 If this post fixed your problem, then please mark it as correct with a green checkmark. This will: (1) show appreciation to the user who gave the correct answer, (2) help future users with a similar issue see that this answer fixed your problem, and (3) help other volunteers by not wasting their time reading questions that already have answers.  Thanks.